# Check that each adjacent pair of a list is in order (tacit programming) in APL

Tags: apl, tacit-programming

Given a list in APL I would like to check that each adjacent pair is in order.
So, given `(a0, a1, ..., an)`, I would like to calculate:

`(a0 ≤ a1) ∧ (a1 ≤ a2) ∧ .... ∧ (a[n-1] ≤ an)`

I don't want to compute an equivalent form and I want to use tacit programming.
My solution is `((¯1↓⊢)∧.≤(1↓⊢))` but it seems too verbose.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: So, in other words, you want to know if a given list is sorted ascending?

Comment: Yes, but using the the formula I indicated.
The formula is equivalent to a series of material implications connected by conjunction (if the list is in binary).  a0 -> a1 AND a1->a2 etc..

Comment: `∧/2≤/⊢` is a shorter form of your formula, but is there a reason you want to use that specific formula?

Comment: @Adám Thank you, I want to be able to write a formal representation of the formula. My goal would be to use apl as a compact tool for representing logical propositions.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Then `∧/2≤/⊢` is strictly follows from your formula by the definition of dyadic `f/`.

Comment: Btw, while I encourage you to keep asking APL questions on SO, know that you're always welcome in [the APL chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard) too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `∧/2≤/⊢`

`X f/ Y` computes the `f`-reductions in `Y` using sliding windows of size `X`. Therefore, if `X←2` then we get pair-wise reductions, or in other words, insertion of `f` between subsequent pairs. `⊢` is needed to complete the 3-train `2 ≤/ ⊢` and then we just have to AND together all the resulting Booleans using `∧/`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for (although the formulation as a ∧.≤ product would have more appeal)

Answer (score 1):

## `⍳∘≢≡⍋`

`⍋` computes the [grade](https://apl.wiki/grade) and if the array is already sorted, then it will simply be an enumeration of the elements, so we use `≡` to compare the grade to `⍳∘≢` which is the indices for an array of the length that your array has.

You can find this on APLcart by [searching for "sorted?"](https://aplcart.info?q=sorted?).

Comment: Thanks but this is an equivalent form to the one I indicated, correct? I would like to calculate exactly and have a formal representation the operation (a0 ≤ a1) ∧ (a1 ≤ a2) ∧ .... ∧ (a[n-1] ≤ an)

Comment: @koteth The two will always give the same result on a real numeric list, however my solution will also work on e.g. complex numbers and higher-rank arrays, by using [total array ordering](https://apl.wiki/total_array_ordering).